# pynput keyboard.type() interference

Tags: python, file, pynput

so i am having some trouble with my code where it recognizes
`keyboard.type()` as a type instead of a string i have all the necessary imports. 
how can i fix this?

```
with open("words.txt") as fp:  
        line = fp.readline()
        cnt = 1
        while line:
                print(line)
                line = fp.readline()

                cnt += 1
                exploit(line)

def exploit(keyboard):
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.type(line)
```

error:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ref.py", line 63, in start
    exploit(line)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ref.py", line 46, in exploit
    keyboard.type("hello")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'type'
```

keyboard modual(https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) is imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have an `import keyboard` line that you're not showing us. (Next time, please provide a complete MCVE).

The problem is on this line:

```
def exploit(keyboard):
```

The `keyboard` module will not be accessible within this function because its name has been overwritten with the `keyboard` parameter you have defined here. If you called `exploit("Hello")`, for example, then this code would attempt to execute `"Hello".type(line)`. But the string has no method named `type`. You probably meant to use the name `line` instead.

```
def exploit(line):
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.type(line)
```

You may be under the impression that a function needs to declare which modules it uses in its signature. This is not the case. Modules imported at the top of your file will be accessible everywhere in that file without you having to do anything special.

Comment: yeah thanks just had to change the location of the def exploit function into the loop it as well